# In Convolutional networks, how to do input data normalization? is it necessary?

Tags: conv-neural-network, normalization, data-preprocessing

I'm wondering about data normalization in CNN, how can we do it for the input images?, what can it add to the model's performance? and what are the main pre-processing techniques before doing the convolutional layer?

Happy to get extra-reading, thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I'm looking for how to practically normalize the data inputs, I didn't get it! 
. Additional reading (explanation, papers) will be so helpful.

Comment: Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336458/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-normalize-data-to-a-nn-or-cnn and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185853/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-the-images-before-we-put-them-into-cnn

Comment: I have updated the question, I didn't understand the normalization procedure, thanks for help

Comment: The three questions that I've linked to appear to address this question. Can you elaborate what you don't understand? "I don't get it!" is not an answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing the data prior to CNN will create more spherical error surfaces which will yield faster convergence of the gradient-based optimization procedure. If this step is skipped, some axes (determined by the eigenvectors of the loss function) will have steeper/flatter structures and consequently, the travel of our optimizer on the surface will get troubled.

You can standardize the images. However, generally, we map the images into 0-1 interval (by dividing to 255 for gray images) so that the values are bounded.